# How can I test history.push inside action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme, redux-thunk

How can I test history.push inside action?

```
export const startLogout = () => {
return ( dispatch ) => {

    return firebase
        .auth()
        .signOut()
        .then(() => {
            dispatch( logout() );
            history.push( '/login' );
        })
        .catch( ( err ) => {
            // Simple redirect to non existent route
            history.push( '/oops' );
            console.log( err );
        });
};
```

};

```
test( 'should start logout', ( done ) => {
const store = createMockStore({});

store.dispatch( startLogout() ).then(() => {
    const actions = store.getActions();

    expect( actions[0] ).toEqual({
        type: LOGOUT
    });

    const history = { push: jest.fn() };
    expect( history.push ).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith( '/login' );

    done();
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log( err );
    done();
});
```

});

This current code gives me this error:

Expected mock function to have been last called with:
        ["/login"]
      But it was not called.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a local `history` object and setting its `push` property to a spy right before you test to see if that local `history.push` spy was called.

You need to create the spy on the `history.push` used in `startLogout`, and it needs to be in place *before* you dispatch the `startLogout` action.